# Typescript : fat arrow & this scope relation

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, this

I was practicing below code 
Code Reference : [Link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/arrow/)

```
   let obj = {
    name : "Cj",   
    sayLater : function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          console.log("sayLater :> "+this.name); 
        },3000)
    },
    sayNow : function(){
      console.log("sayNow :> "+this.name); 
    },
    sayLaterFA : function(){
      setTimeout(() => console.log("sayLaterFA :> "+this.name) ,3000)
    },
    sayNowFA : () => console.log("sayNowFA :> "+this.name),
    sayLaterPureFatArrow : () => { setTimeout(() => console.log("sayLaterPureFatArrow :> "+this.name),4000) },
    sayNowPureFatArrow : () => { console.log("sayNowPureFatArrow :> "+this.name) }
  }



 obj.sayLater();             //Output : sayLater :> undefined
  obj.sayNow();               //Output : sayNow :> Cj
  obj.sayLaterFA();           //Output : sayLaterFA :> Cj 
  obj.sayNowFA();             //Output : sayNowFA :> Cj
  obj.sayLaterPureFatArrow(); //Output : sayLaterPureFatArrow :> undefined 
  obj.sayNowPureFatArrow();   //Output : sayNowPureFatArrow :> undefined
```

Can anyone explain me why my output is undefined though I am using fat arrow function

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fat arrows capture the *surrounding `this` value*. For an expression in an object literal at the top level of a file, the *surrounding `this` value* is `window` (non-strict mode) or `undefined` (strict mode).

So the behavior you see is:

- `sayLater`: `undefined` because the inner function uses no `this`-capturing mechanism (thus `this` is "lost" and goes back to `window` / `undefined`)
- `sayNow`: `Cj` because of the normal `this` semantics (`this` is "what's to the left of the `.`" in a method invocation)
- `sayLaterFA` - same as `sayNow` except that the inner function captured the outer function's "correct" `this`
- `sayNowFA` - poorly named because it's identical to `sayNow`
- `sayLaterPureFatArrow` / `sayLaterPureFatArrow` - both captured `window` as `this`

Answer (score 3):

The `this` value for those arrow functions is the value of `this` in the context where the functions were created. That's *not* the object you're constructing; it's whatever `this` is where that object initializer code exists.

In other words, inside

```
let obj = {
  // whatever
};
```

the value of `this` does not change from what it is before or after that initialization. The language does not provide a way to refer to an "under construction" object in an initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `this` referring to the object a arrow function is in in an arrow function,

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this[...]

This will always refer to the object you are calling from, i.e. `window` in a browser

Comment: *"This will always refer to the object you are calling from"* What exactly is that supposed to mean? In an arrow function, `this` is resolved lexically like any other variable.

Comment: In Case of obj.sayLater();  function has been called but setTimeout has only been initialed.At the time of setTimeout executes the console.log the value of this will be undefined in that function scope.Am I right @Luca

Comment: Your are right, @CJ

Answer (score 0):

`undefiend` is shown as output, since `this` refers to the scope inside the `setTimeout()` function where `name` isn't available, hence, `undefined`

I usually do it something on the lines of

```
ayLater : function(){ let instance = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("sayLater :> "+instance.name); 
    },3000)
},
```

Hope this answers :)

Comment: This is not accurate; the question is not about the behavior of `setTimeout()` but about how the arrow functions are created.

Comment: Also, if `this` was undefined then `this.name` would throw. `this` simply refers to the global scope when the arrow function is not within another function scope.

Comment: Yes, both of you are correct. There was a slight misunderstanding on my side. Also, have updated my answer to rectify

Comment: yeah @AseemUpadhyay if we do it your way it will print the the name for sure.. As instance will hold the value of variable.